# Debug option INITDEBUG, output format

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

Ghostscript has the debug option `INITDEBUG` which outputs this:

```bash
END PROCS 0 1523912 211486 1330832 36164 true 662 3 <0>
gs_std_e.ps 0 1523912 217533 1330832 38644 true 670 3 <0>
gs_il1_e.ps 0 1523912 222799 1330832 38644 true 671 3 <0>
END FONTDIR/ENCS 0 1523912 223027 1330832 38644 true 673 3 <0>
END DEVS 0 1593776 305009 1330832 38644 true 677 3 <0>
END STATD 0 1613976 322087 1330832 41524 true 682 3 <0>
END GS_FONTS 0 1664328 378150 1330832 41524 true 711 3 <0>
END BASIC COLOR 0 1704728 391377 1330832 41524 true 727 3 <0>
...
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find any information about the format of the output. Does anyone know what all of these values mean?

Comment: Yes, they are the module being assessed, the output of vmstatus (separately for local and global VM if the system is level 2+) the current VM allocation mode if the system is level 2+, usertime, the length (number of entries) of systemdict, the number of entries on the dictionary stack and the number of entries on the operand stack. If you are a skilled PostScript programmer you should be able to deduce that from the fact that 'END PROCS' is in gs_init.ps and executes VMDEBUG, reading VMDEBUG tells you what it prints. PostScript programmers will know what all that means.

Comment: But fundamentally these are only of any use to Ghostscript developers.

Comment: @KenS I see, thanks! I'm not a GS developer, and that's why I was struggling to interpret.